# Not able to create a user with Firebase Auth

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

Error I'm getting:

> this.auth.createUser is not a function

According to the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#create_a_user)
I should be able to create a user like so:

```
admin.auth().createUser({
  email: 'user@example.com',
  emailVerified: false,
  phoneNumber: '+11234567890',
  password: 'secretPassword',
  displayName: 'John Doe',
  photoURL: 'http://www.example.com/12345678/photo.png',
  disabled: false
})
```

My code:

```
   import app from 'firebase/app';
    import 'firebase/auth';

class Firebase {
  constructor() {
    app.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

    this.auth = app.auth();
  }

      doCreateExistingUserAuth = (uid, email, password) =>
          this.auth.createUser({
            uid: uid,
            email: email,
            password: password
          })
```

When I execute this I get the error stated above.  Any ideas what I"m doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation you're linking to is for the Firebase Admin SDK, which is for backends only.  For frontend web applications, there is no ability to create a new user.  If you want a user to be able to create another user account, you will have to call through to some backend, where you can use the Admin SDK.

Comment: Uhm... "...for front-end JavaScript applications, you'll want to use this [Firebase Authentication JavaScript SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth#create_a_password-based_account), with which you create a user who is then immediately signed in to the application." :)

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen And we know how many people get tripped up on that unexpected behavior!